# Coloring a graph with three colors

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Is the statement below correct?

A graph which doesn't have a complete graph of order $4$ or more can be colored with $3$ colors, so that no two adjacent vertices have same color.

I don't know it is correct or not; if it is not correct, please someone give me a counterexample to that.

Comment: No two adjacent vertices have same color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counterexample:** Take the cycle $C_5$ and add a sixth vertex which is adjacent to all of the old vertices.